# How to overcome "Edits must be at least 6 characters"

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, faq-proposed, character-limit

On Stack Overflow, there was a question with an incorrectly formatted list, which lacked a newline before it and thus came out like this:
1. Hello
2. Something else
3. Goodbye

I changed it to the right formatting by inserting a newline:

1. Hello
2. Something else
3. Goodbye

And I got the "Edits must be at least 6 characters" error message. Is there an OK way to trick this rule?

Comment: Just remove "Hello" and "Thanks" in top and bottom of the post :)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82534/change-this-behavior-to-allow-for-spelling-corrections-and-the-like-edits-must/82535#82535

Comment: This is annoying for source code changes, where only a `;` is missing …

Comment: It makes me angry, too. If I see a simple syntax error, like a misplaced comma, I then have to start adding noise to the post just to make the edit stick.

Even worse when a poster doesn't know how to use indenting and then the blank spaces don't even count towards the 6 characters.

I like SO but not this rule.

Comment: @fritzfromlondon I think the accepted answer has the solution: there is always something else to do even if it is not your primary objective when pushing the edit button. You can change the text a little bit to make it more readable or undertsandable.

Comment: Rules with magic numbers (like 6 in this case) are always bad rules.

Comment: @Dominik SO likes to have constraints on pretty much every variable not to get out of control (like daily rep cap or vote cap). It's not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: @vbence: No, there isn't *always* something else to do.  Sometimes there is, often there isn't.  Preventing people from making important edits because they can't find any additional inconsequential edits to make is stupid.

Comment: vbence, please, for the love of god (or the hate of god, or the apathy towards god, whichever you like best), accept the better (next-highest) answer.

Comment: @codetaku IMO *doing some more work on the post* is the better solution. It will make the content better quality. Also, hacking in irrelevant HTML changes will make the quality of the content worse. - Especially with the rep farming going on these days by new users, flooding the site with insignificant edits.

Comment: I found an answer in which both the terms "CPU" and "GPU" were used, since it was a question about both. In the otherwise good answer, the author used the term "GPU" instead of "CPU". While this is only a 1 character error, it drastically changes the meaning. I'm not sure how to get around this, so it's left unedited...

Comment: @orrymr easy, since you already see how error-prone this can be, why not change the wording to something less so? Maybe using "Graphics Processor" instead of GPU?

Comment: @vbence, that's a good idea :)

Comment: It's not just formatting or typos, either. A lot of the time- for example, in shell scripts- the entire thing is wrong if it forgets to put double quotes around a variable or lacks an `&` at the end of a line.

Comment: @dokaspar: Rules like you cannot drink booze under age of 18/21?

Comment: @VajkHermecz, that rule seems to be a good example:  it is clear that there is no magical transition that happens upon turning 18 in some countries, or 21 in others.  A (logically) better rule would be some sort of competency-oriented test, but of course that would be an impracticable nightmare to implement, so we settle for a bad test as better than no test.

Comment: Yep­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: there is a way to trick it.

Comment: @LSpice I wonder how many lives would be saved if drinking required a safety class and competency test first instead of an arbitrary age limit.

Comment: The 6 character rule discourages people from making valid/needed changes--and actually starts working ***against*** quality--because for posts that have already been reviewed by hundreds or thousands of people already, there actually aren't too many ways to make these posts better....it's usually just some some non-major (but still important) thing that needs changing and we don't want to add noise just to make that change because it would decrease the quality of the post.  So the minor mistakes remain.  Why not make the number 1 instead of 6?

Comment: IMHO, the solution is as simple as *asking* the person whether there is anything else they can improve. And giving them the option to say "No, just accept my edit". If that is deemed "too lenient", then require them to give a reason why such a small edit is significant enough to submit. In my case, the answer is usually "the f*ing code doesn't compile without this syntax change, so let me make the damn change".

Comment: So this is still being discussed and seen after 9 years but nobody's considered fixing it?  All I wanted to do is remove the spaces at the beginning which was stuffing up the formatting. I'm not going to waste my time trying to improve stackoverflow (and other stack-exchange sites) if it's going to tell me off for making "too small" of a change.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change this behavior to allow for spelling corrections and the like: "Edits must be at least 6 characters"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82534/change-this-behavior-to-allow-for-spelling-corrections-and-the-like-edits-must)

Comment: This silly rule discourages making reasonable improvements on SO. Out of several annoying, but disputable rules, this one is outright silly and evil. And it has been requested and discussed for at least 10 years to remove this rule, but it is still active. F*** ** **!

Comment: This is untested: Maybe you can make your single character change, add some gibberish at the bottom, save, then edit it again, removing the gibberish but leaving your single character change. If it works, it seems easier on the editor than https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90014/206361 but, it's probably worse on the reviewers.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sure! Instead of tricking the rule, just look for other changes that can be made. Usually, in a post that forgets that kind of formatting, there's often at least one other error to be found. A miscapitalized letter, an extra space, or often just another formatting error of a different sort.

Remember, when you suggest an edit, it requires multiple other people to look at it and approve it. The character limit is to prevent people from wasting time by looking at exceptionally minor edits. So, don't limit yourself to just a tiny edit: *try to see if you can improve the post to a possible state of perfection*. If you hit *all* errors on a post, then no one else will even need to edit it.

Once you hit 2k reputation, and thus your edits don't need to go through the approval process, you can make those tiny changes without the limit in the way.

Comment: Are you sure of "no limit over 2k"? I seem to be hitting the limit, even at 16k - but as it does prompt me to make other changes, it makes me realize that any edit should improve the post *considerably*, therefore I do more editing.

Comment: @Piskvor Quite positive. Even if I didn't have first-hand experience of it, Jeff and waffles have stressed, multiple times, that if you find that rare instance that it's just a minor edit of under 6 characters, just let a 2k user handle it. Because 2k users don't need to bother 2 other users just to get their edit through.

Comment: @Piskvor - I can confirm that the 6 character limit doesn't apply to 100K users. ;-) _ok, technically, 133K users, but I doubt anyone would pick 133K as an arbitrary cutoff, maybe 128K, but not 133K._

Comment: @tvanfosson: Well, time for me to get some more rep then ;) It could have been me clicking "improve this edit" and triggering the 6-char edit limit there...

Comment: I beg to disagree just because code snippets need spaces in front. So space only changes are not uncommon. In fact, you got it the wrong way around: When all you do is add spaces then then you can't do any evil with it. No 2k users needed.

BTW: not knowing the background all i did make a useless 6 character change and a rant in the explanation. Now there will be some 2k users having fun now.

Comment: But what if there *aren't* any other changes to be made?  The people who make up these rules don't seem to think them through before implementing them.

Comment: As a new user I can say this limit is rather annoying. In StackOverflow I saw a code snippet where someone had an extra e in their code. All I wanted to do was remove the extra e so the code would compile. It would not let me change a reference of *Neested*  to *Nested* to prevent a compile error.

Comment: @Grace: How do we "let a 2k user handle it" if they aren't aware of the problem?  I thought the whole point of this limit was to prevent bothering 2k users who have to review every edit anyway.

Comment: @JSWork if the posted code would not compile, surely that was the problem the asker was facing? See my answer below.

Comment: @Kate Gregory: If I recall correctly it was more of a "try this solution" post. The solution was right, there was just a typo in one of the variable names in the form of an extra *e*.

Comment: Small changes can make the difference between correct and incorrect code. For example, this XAML here needs quotes to work:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948290/why-fontstretch-does-not-work-in-wpf

I didn't see anything else to improve, but it would be a convenience to other people copying and pasting the code to try it out, if the code were correct.

Comment: would be interesting to know how do you submit "improved" edit suggestion for this code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8722074/155687 - there is ONLY ONE character to delete (mismatch in regex and error message)

    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="valInput"
        ControlToValidate="txtInput"
        ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{0,100}$"
        ErrorMessage="Please enter a maximum of 1000 characters"
        Display="Dynamic">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

Comment: I would argue against the "state of perfection." Perfection doesn't matter. Editing to that extent has diminishing returns.

Comment: @OP: "Instead of tricking the rule, just look for other changes that can be made [...] there's often at least one other error to be found". -> That's simply not true.

Comment: -1, sometimes there isn't

Comment: *sigh* This is painful when someone whose first language is probably not English has given a good answer - except for confusing a pair of English homonymns, creating nonsense. "Exits" and "exists" in this case. Even with my proofreader's eagle eye, I only found one other similar mistake (its for it's IIRC) and had to change a perfectly valid word to a synonymn to increase my character count. Even with my explanation in the edit reason, reviewers are going to see the silly change first - the important typo was in the last line of the answer - and probably disallow the edit. *sigh*

Comment: It is really annoying when you find that the only way of making a posting perfect is to change one letter, and you can't do it. "Play a trick and you can do your minor edit" is a rule that is hard to motivate.

Comment: I'm surprised that the comments on this answer are almost exclusively negative. I think the motivation is that **setting a minimum does more _good_ by preventing a flow of extremely minor / pedantic edits (especially from new users), than it does _evil_ by bothering users (who were already willing to click and punch a few buttons to edit) to find 1 or 2 more things to edit.** I get that one character makes all the difference in code, but most edits are _not_ of that nature, and even among the ones that are, we can almost always find something else to edit, in less than 15 seconds, and

Comment: usually for the benefit of all. And if you don't? That is, if you come across that rare post that _absolutely_ needs a few characters to change (and otherwise readers will be totally misled), but is otherwise perfect? Well, tough luck! You've been had! You've been took! You've been hoodwinked! Bamboozled! Led astray! Run amok! By the universe. _And_ no >2K user finds it (or finds it important enough) to edit it? Sorry it happened to you, but personally, I still prefer the minimum to exist.

Comment: _"A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds."_ Most people understand things just fine despite bad spelling and/or grammar (and if it's really that bad, then you're gonna have more than 6 characters to edit). And most mindless typos in code will reveal themselves as errors (and if not, _i.e._ a missing semicolon after a class, which may trigger error messages that send new users barking up the wrong tree, then just _leave a comment_).

Comment: -1 I also dislike the "rules are smarter than reality" attitude of this rule. At the very least, there should be "I'm sure there is nothing else to fix" override button.

Comment: I recently tried to fix a broken link which required removing 3 characters. Couldn't do it so I left it as is. It's extremely discouraging as I spent a couple of minutes finding out the correct URL. I probably won't do that again.

Comment: @acheong87 You're making 2 invalid assumptions. 1. A flow of minor/pedantic edits is a good thing, not a bad thing; anything that improves the site's content should be welcomed.  2. Character count is not in any way related to the importance of an edit.  Some small edits are extremely helpful, some small edits are not.  Some large edits are helpful, some large edits are pointless.

Comment: @Aaron I agree. When they ask a question like that one, they don't really expect a negative answer. It would be like saying, "Aren't there other ways to improve this post?" to which the correct answer would be assumed: "Of course! How silly of me! Yes, there are!" Of course, a human being would know the difference, but a script just obeys the instructions it received from its author. It's like the line by Will Smith from _I, Robot:_ "Just lights and clockwork."

Comment: So in order to not waste reviewers' time with a bunch of unnecessary edits, we should hide our necessary edit in a pile of unnecessary edits?

Comment: @AndrewCheong When I see an obvious single fault in a text, I don't think it is fussy to correct it in the first place, nor do I find it reasonable to conclude that I now have to draw my full attention to the whole of the post, regardless of my intentions or qualifications as to its special content, or field of expertise. As I understand it, this is always intended to be a collaborative effort where also small contributions count.

Comment: Perhaps this rule could be escaped in code blocks then. Many times I've copied either incorrect code or out of date shell/batch commands. Especially in the latter case updating them ensures that answers always remain up-to-date and additionally could result in less noise overall. Which adds more noise/confusion to the site: a few edits on some code or a nearly duplicate question because the original one was slightly out of date and a confused user wasn't able to figure out a solution?

Comment: That answer don't work. It happens that a post has a simple typo, switched characters or missing or wrong character. Nothing else to edit in the post. The limit is just stupid.

Comment: Ran into the six character limitation, became pissed, Googled, and found this answer. Then I reread the post I was editing, and realized there were actually lots more tiny improvements I could make. System working as intended!

Comment: No, That's fine. We will just leave typos so uninformed user can become even more perplexed. We are uber-geeks after all

Comment: Sorry, I can't see any possible harm coming from allowing users to suggest edits that may involve a small number of characters but a significant improvement in post clarity.

Comment: some code format edits really improve a question. But changing other stuff in the question is useless and wasting the time of the person improving the question.

Comment: _"Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved"_  the irony =/. 
Sometimes I dont feel like searching around for several minutes to find 6 characters in a smallish post. I just want to make "ad-hock" read "ad-hoc".   This rule forces me to make changes possibly outside of the original author's intent just to fix a common spelling mistake..

Comment: -1 This is a _wrong_ assumption.

Comment: @GraceNote Wow how stupid is that?  just look for other changes that can be made. So you suggest to invent new problems where no other problem exist. People like you have a rep over 80k. because of guys like you this site is so bad and probably u are using your digital power to shut others down. Bravo

Comment: Today I saw a typo on an otherwise excellent answer. Two letters were transposed. Easy to fix. Hard to find "something else to improve," and especially if it's something I'm not actually an expert in, I worry about making the post worse. And of course, if I were an expert, I wouldn't be looking at this answer. So I added an extra comments asking the edit-approver to delete it. Pedantic changes will usually be over 6 characters anyway (trust me, I know pedantic). This adds a large cognitive load to otherwise helpful edits. I like the suggestion of adding an HTML comment, from @endolith, below.

Comment: -1, sometimes there isn't

Comment: Please remove the min char change for edits rule.

Answer (score 286):

To circumvent this counterproductive rule [without confusing the recipient of your edits](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/56590/7788), just add a `&nbsp;` or HTML comment `<!---->` at the end of a line, where it won't make any difference to the formatting.

If Stack Exchange adds a rule to ban *those* (because they *really* prefer that you don't fix typos and mistakes), then you'll have to be creative with other non-printing or whitespace elements.

The *How to Edit* box next to the edit window encourages exactly these kinds of changes:

> How to Edit
>
> ► fix grammatical or spelling errors
>
> ► correct minor mistakes

So it's pretty hypocritical for the site to reject your helpful contributions after explicitly asking for them.

Comment: Another thing you could add: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91535/130885

Comment: Nice hack. It's a completely stupid rule when you want to change a code error such as "dict*" to "*dict"

Comment: ... or "dic_" to "dict"

Comment: This needs to be the accepted answer for _so many reasons_.

Comment: Probably I missed something, I didn't understand how to use `&nbsp;` but this empty space is OK, I copy it by holding `SHIFT` and pressing arrows http://fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/browsertest.htm: `->​<-`.
BTW this is not only SO rule... I've seen multiple forums and communities with this, I really wish a SO admin to comment on this: WHY?

Comment: @Kremchik You just type `&nbsp;` somewhere at the end of a line.

Comment: It's even better to add an HTML comment (`<!---->`) because it doesn't display at all.

Comment: Another example of nonsensical edits to meet the quota for a single character change: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/posts/472/revisions

Comment: StackOverflow is making a joke of themselves here.

Comment: My usual approach is to add this at the end:

`<!-- character limits are dumb: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90014/238319 -->`

Comment: This situation is ridiculous. Who says a 1 char edit cannot be valuable?

Comment: I like @JakeRobb's approach, I'll use that in the future. Stupid rule based on an unfounded assertion.

Comment: Sorry to necro this, but I just ran into a mildly obnoxious situation where I edited an answer and had to include an invisible character to get the edit over the 6-character limit. My edit then got approved, and then the user who approved it edited it again just to remove my invisible character. Now it says that the post was "edited by" this other user, when literally all they did was remove an invisible character that didn't change the resulting post at all. It's a very minor thing, but it's a bit annoying to have my work attributed to another user who just made a useless edit.

Comment: It's also quite ironic that this system stopped me from making a totally valid edit by forcing me to use a cheap workaround, but then some other user makes a _truly useless_ edit and the system just lets it go. It kind of emphasizes how flawed this system really is.

Comment: @OOPSStudio "Necro" isn't a thing.

Answer (score 80):

I disagree with the premise that small edits are a bother to the reviewers. I only recently hit the threshold (for having edits applied directly and for reviewing others) and I think the smaller the edit is, the easier it is to approve. If I see a small typo being fixed, code formatted, or a sentence properly capitalized, I can see right away what it is and approve it.

The bigger the edit is, the longer it takes to check.

I say the 6 character limit needs to be abandoned.

Comment: It is easier and quicker to review one edit rather than several - you have to read the whole question/answer to make sure that it is a reasonable edit - if you are not doing this then you are not reviewing

Comment: @Mark But I'm not suggesting to spread out one big edit among several small ones, I'm arguing that sometimes a small edit is all that's needed. And if I see that the only difference is a typo being fixed, I don't _have_ to read the entire post to judge the edit.

Comment: The issue raised by others is if there is an error in formatting then there is likely to be other errors - so a small edit is likely to be a too minor edit

Comment: @Mark Yes, but that's not always the case. Sometimes it's just the one typo that _needs_ to be fixed to have the answer make sense.

Comment: I agree with your premise, @SQB, and let me say also that the two rules "Edits must be at least 6 characters long" and "Above all, respect the original poster" could potentially be at odds with each other. Sometimes scouring the post for multiple mistakes or making some picky formatting change just to rise above 6 characters can be disrespectful of the author, unless it actually does improve something about the post; and likewise the correction of a "minor" error (as measured by the number of characters) can be much more respectful of the original poster. Just a thought.

Comment: I don't think that changing a single "i" to "I" is worth 2 reputation points. This alone is reason enough to leave the limit in place.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Then the system *shouldn't award reputation points* for single-character edits.  You're conflating 2 different things.  Small edits should be accepted regardless of whether they give rep or not, since they're beneficial and reduce reader confusion.

Comment: @endolith there's already such a feature request, but the thing to consider here is the required development time vs. how important this really is. With thousands of users actively editing and great majority of posts needing more than 6 characters edits, the team better spend their time on developing better things.

Comment: @ShadowWizard "required development time vs. how important this really is"  Accuracy is important.

Comment: @Mark In response to: "if there is an error in formatting then there is likely to be other errors", I don't think that's logically justifiable when a post has been seen by hundreds of people and edited by several.  I found a post upvoted by 338 people.  It was very well written and had probably been edited many times.  But it still had only one issue I could see: the word "and" was used where it should have been "are".  I had to read the phrase a couple times to know the intended meaning--I don't think that's "too minor" of an edit when probably 1000s of others are having to do the same thing.

Answer (score 48):

It is incorrect for a 6 character limitation to be imposed. When you edit at top of the page there is:

> We welcome all constructive edits, but please make them substantial. Avoid trivial, tiny one-letter edits unless absolutely necessary.

So what to do when absolutely necessary? That limitation needs to be removed and normal approval process take place or the above text needs to be changed with other suggestions.

P.S. I liked the answer to add non-printable characters to post. I didn't think they were counted.

Comment: But the point is that SO won't LET you do a 1 letter edit without resorting to these silly hacks. And it isn't "trivial" if there's a typo in a code example that simply won't work because of it.

Comment: A tiny edit is not necessarily a trivial one (if you ask a compiler).

Comment: I wanted to fix a typo of *were* to *where*, but I couldn't, because 6char. Thanks, Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 27):

The limit is stupid. Sometimes there are simple typos, easy to fix - but only one character. Post would improve. And nobody can tell me reviewers are overloaded because of this, because in SE-sites I can access the review-queue I have to submit much much less time with approving simple edits like fixing typos than with complicated edits. A fixed typo is easy to see.

Even worse, sometimes I find simple edits that fix something - and then do something with formatting or similar that makes the post worse. I assume that was done to reach the 6 characters.

Based on my experience as reviewer in some sites and suggesting edits in others I would say: make the edit and if it doesn't reach 6 characters add following to the end of the post:

```
<!-- character-limit: please remove -->
```

Reviewers have an 'Approve and edit'-button, so it is still simple enough to work with and it is easy to understand what the edit is for.

Answer (score 26):

Some people feel there should be an exception to this rule for single-character errors in code. (There is a general consensus that single-character errors in sentences are highly unlikely to matter.) My approach to this is:

If it's not your question, and you see a one-character typo, your ANSWER is "hey, OP, you have a one character typo: you have [line paste] where you should have [corrected line].

If it's your question, you update it and add "Update: Sorry, when sanitizing this code I made a one-character typo: the code that causes the problem did not have [error] where it should be [correction] and I've corrected my sanitized version in this question." Now the 400+ answerers who are telling you about the typo can delete their answers.

Either way, you avoid the single-character edit.

Comment: If it's your own question, then there is no 6 character limit.

Comment: @Grace - Thanks. I still feel people who edit typos out of the code in their questions should, if there are answers or comments referring to the typo, add explanatory text identifying the typo as a red herring.

Comment: @KateGregory: That's why you can flag comments as "obsolete" and have them removed.  One of the big things that makes Stack Exchange better than forums is that you don't need to wade through pages of discussion to get the information you need.  Users have a discussion about some point in an answer, the outcome of the discussion is edited back into the answer, and then the obsolete discussion is deleted.  Distill out the important content and delete the chaff.

Comment: But then there are the idiots who get upvotes for /answers/, rather than comments, that achieve nothing other than pointing out the typo. How do we mark those as obsolete?

Comment: @codetaku: Can you show an example? Flag them as "not an answer".

Comment: "there is a general consensus that single-character errors in sentences are highly unlikely to matter", have you got a source for that claim on consensus?  I've just ended up here because someone's answer included a file path with a missing backslash somewhere in the middle of the long path that took me time to figure out the right place.  And so it will for the next person.

Comment: a file path is not a sentence. It's more like code, @AlanMacdonald. Other than typing now/not in "this is now possible" **words** in **sentences** tend to be pretty typo proof.

Comment: @KateGregory in my rage at the 6 character edit rule I never read what you were saying properly.  I understand now thanks.

Comment: A single character can break code, can make a math formula wrong, can misspell a word (sometimes changing its meaning), and can break formatting. Even if that character is whitespace. We should encourage such critically-important small edits while discouraging weakly-motivated extensive edits. (Nobody likes seeing their own contributions substantially rephrased for no real reason.) What if the reviewer overlooks the small change and objects to the superfluous changes that must be bundled with it?

Comment: Is it just me or is it laughable that this post is recommending people create and delete 400 answers rather than make one single-character edit? Or is it meant to be satire and I'm just missing the joke? "To avoid the inconvenience of having to review a single-character edit, why don't you just type a 300-character answer instead and then monitor this post so you can come back and delete it when it's no longer relevant? Isn't that much simpler?"

Comment: Also, "There is a general consensus that single-character errors in sentences are highly unlikely to matter." And this is according to who? From what I can see, the "general consensus" is that every single person in this thread disagrees with this statement. Is there really such a small difference between "closest positioned" and "closest, positioned" ?

Answer (score 21):

I encountered the same problem, where the person that answered the question did a great job with the answer, but the links were off. So I had to edit just 3 characters.

It was an old post, I believe no one ever fixed it because of the 6 characters limitation.

It seems rather counterproductive that in order to fix a small problem you have to look around to be able to add valuable information.

What if you are like me? I found that question because I was learning about the subject. How could I add valuable information to an answer that was already correct except for the links being off? (btw just 2 links were off, so the answer had enough information to be understood).

I understand that there are people that review the corrections, and minor changes, like correcting a typo that is easy to understand would be hard to review, but I don't know, maybe something should be done for special cases like the one I had with the links.

Comment: I suppose the passive-aggressive approach would be to flag the post for ♦ moderator attention and describe the needed correction in the flag description. Overkill, sure, but at least the mods _can_ make the edit. Not that I'd seriously advocate actually doing this.

Comment: More practically, you could describe the problem in a comment. If the author of the post is still around, they'll be notified about it, and in any case the comment will at least inform readers about the issue.

Comment: Well we could do all that and more. I looked for an additional link in my case. But It is an overkill! And it kinda goes against the website goal: "Stack Overflow is as frictionless and painless to use as we could make it."

Comment: Similar thing happened to me: I had a problem, found an old Q&A, followed a link to "more info", corrected the link as it didn't work, and ... had my edit rejected as being insignificant! That rejection was a greater time-waster (and insulter) than if it would have been accepted. Shame on the petty, hypocritical pedants at SO!

Answer (score 12):

I have used the `&nbsp;` trick a few times, but I find myself adding the `backticks:` ` for code formatting around *missed* inline formats.

By highlighting these it only takes a few of them to help with the char count, but it also emphasizes often missed inline code examples.

**NOTE:** This is not a hack...
Rather, this is a way to add to char count by observing often overlooked formatting techniques.

Comment: If the downvotes here are to indicate "please don't abuse code formatting", please note that that's not what the author seems to be suggesting. If I understand correctly, he's merely stating that authors tend to occasionally forget to properly format their in-line code. In which case formatting it would be appropriate. Of course it isn't a general highlighting tool.

Comment: Thank you @Bart for clarifying.. I will update the post as such. i do not mean to "hack" the system, just add another suggestion for ways to add to character count that is often overlooked in the fury of typing the question first time through.

Comment: It's just that we have rather a lot of formatting abuse @Phlume, where users highlight every other word with code formatting. So I can see how users might misinterpret your suggestion. If it's not code, don't format it as such. If it is, then it's a valid suggestion.

Comment: @Bart Agreed. Thank you for the help clarifying for the users.. not perhaps a reversal could be in order from the DV peeps??

Comment: @Phlume Do you mean `now`?  :)

Answer (score 10):

This may be bending the rules, but here's a little trick I've found. You can edit the misspelled word, then add an empty HTML comment tag afterwards. For example:

```
The sum of it's effects
```

could be changed to:

```
The sum of its <!-- --> effects
```

which displays as:

The sum of its  effects

It gets the job done for an edit of only one character. Then when the edit has been approved, you can reedit to remove the extra characters, if you want. Or it may be left in place, to be removed at the next legitimate edit.

But use this sparingly; if everyone used it just to circumvent the rule, it would eventually be banned. So use it only when you can change nothing else!

Of course, you don't have to put the comment tag close to the edit; it can actually be placed anywhere in the post.

Comment: @Bart you're the only commenter, so I'll ask you: should I delete the SE suggestion, or is my post completely irrelevant to the question?

Comment: If you're referring to the downvotes, I can only assume they have been cast in disagreement with your work-around. If you feel it's a valid and acceptable practice, you can leave it in place. But the community doesn't seem to think it is.

Comment: One comment about my comment above: it refers to a suggestion to SE which is no longer in this post. I left it in place because it would be even more confusing if I didn't leave some context to @bart's comment.

Comment: My trick is replacing any dot you want with a italic dot: `<em>.</em>`

Comment: Looking at this example, it would make sense to put a comment that "it's" is wrong here, possibly with a link to a page discussing the difference, inside the html comment. Having the comment may then also well be within the rules, i.e. no more rule bending.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another workaround: Add 6 random characters, then make a follow on edit to remove those 6 characters.

Comment: I like the way you think, but please avoid this kind of noise in the edit history. At least use this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90014/254218)

Comment: It doesn't have to be noise. It can be "Adding some characters to be deleted in the next edit to get around the rule requiring edits to be at least 6 characters, since this edit is just fixing a typo". I think either this was or the one suggested in the answer you linked are fine, but the <!-- --> answer wasn't working for me, so the other one might break as well, in which case this would be the only option.

Answer (score 1):

I personally believe that the 6 characters rule is not really much necessary.

But anyway, another way to overcome the limit (that has not yet been mentioned), if you are just correcting a single typo or spelling error, then you can just as well leave it in a comment. And leave it up to the original poster to edit it (and possibly they may wish to apply other (positive) changes while being reminded of their old post with tiny error.)

Comment: Well this is relevant only if the post author is still around.

Comment: Also include edit instructions (e.g. a live link in the comment to ["edit"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/337988/edit)) - as the entire concept of editing may be foreign (from the forum mindset). Otherwise, it may never happen; or they respond in comments instead.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `$\!$` to bypass the character requirement. Just add more `\!` as needed.

Note: This only works on sites with LaTeX enabled.

Comment: This seems to be strictly inferior to the already-given workarounds that *don't* require MathJax to be enabled.

Comment: &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;

Comment: @NathanTuggy As you can see, the &nbsp; trick does not work in comments

Comment: But you can't edit others' comments, and as far as I know you can edit your own comments without character restrictions as long as you're within the 5-minute window, so this isn't necessary or useful.

Comment: @NathanTuggy But if mathjax is enabled, this way is obviously superior

Comment: The MathJax way doesn't allow you to do anything you can't already do (in particular, it hasn't the slightest effect on the ability to edit comments), is less clear than some other methods, and requires a dependency that will consume noticeable CPU power when rendered and is only available on certain sites, which increases mental load to remember two methods. I don't see any way in which it is anything but inferior.

Comment: It is not less clear, and has negligible impact on mental load. It is superior in the fact that it can be used in comments.

Comment: *MathJax* can be used in comments. *The MathJax edit trick* can't, because **comments have no minimum-length edit requirement in the first place**, so this answer's rationale for superiority appears to be missing the point of the question, which is to allow edits (to others' posts, with less than 2k rep) which would otherwise be prevented because they're too small. The given MathJax trick *can* do that, but only in a strict subset of the conditions that every other trick listed can: only on MathJax sites. It *can't* change the fact that the trick is only meaningful in posts. Not comments.

Comment: But it is a perfectly valid alternative method; also comments have a 15 character minimum requirement; this trick allows you to bypass that. And I know that isn't the main point of this post but that doesn't mean this trick doesn't work.

Comment: Both are true, but that's why I consider this method strictly inferior *for this question*, which isn't about (comment) posting minimums, only edit minimums.