# What is the proper way to correct a typo?

Tags: support, edits, spelling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to overcome “Edits must be at least 6 characters”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters)

I want to correct a typo on a post where the correction modifies less than 6 characters. How can I do this? I assume that adding random characters would be bad comedy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. The general SO opinion about this is that you shouldn't fix a minor typo without also making other — more substantial — edits to a post.

Which is reflected by not allowing you to do that when you have less than 2k rep.

Comment: @Killbog: Subtle... but that's a privilege for 2k+ rep users only, like mentioned in my answer ;-) I do agree that it is sometimes worthwhile to do minor typo fixes. I personally can't leave a wrong `its` or `it's` for instance as it totally messes up my flow if I encounter one.

Answer (score 4):

Either find something else to edit, or cheat.  It's kind of a silly rule, since there are many times you don't need six chars.