# Why the limit for minimum of characters for editing?

Tags: support, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to overcome “Edits must be at least 6 characters”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters)

I just tried to fix a misspelled word in an answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1903054/106248

It's "aslo" instead of "also".

Than I get: "Edits must be at least 6 characters".
So no way to fix this kind of misspelling?

And while we are at it - I got this error after it made me write an explanation: "Please enter a comment explaining your edit". So, I'm writing an explanation and than it doesn't let me post it...