# Can't suggest minor but important edit

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to overcome “Edits must be at least 6 characters”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters)

Recently I came across [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1169067/522050)

It has so many upvotes but it is not working because  answerer got it wrong this line

```
NSKeyedArchiver  *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
```

It should be corrected as

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver  *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
```

So I tried to correct it by adding `Un` to answer body. But I got this message.

> Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
>
> Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to
>   improve in this post?

Is it wrong to correct a answer like this?

Comment: Even if it had more than 6 chars, that edit is likely to be rejected by the reviewers because it changes the code. (Not saying that's right, just what's likely to happen). There's a comment on the post that also says it should be "NsKeyedUnarchiver", best thing to do is upvote that comment.

Comment: Find something else to edit. For example, there are several identifiers in text that aren't formatted as code. @S.L.Barth Even without knowing Objective-C, it's clear that the class names must match, and that this bit was copy-pasted and the author forgot to edit one piece. I know that reviewers often get it wrong, but it's no reason to discourage correct edits.