# Use the wording and links of "you don't have edit privileges" banner from mobile web in the desktop version

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, mobile-web, full-site

Prompted by the comments on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/328526/398063).

On mobile, when I try to edit a post on a site I don't have edit privileges on, I get this banner:

> You do not have [edit privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit). Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed.

Or alternatively:

> You are not [logged in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/join?ssrc=suggested_edit). Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is [peer reviewed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit).

The difference being an additional registration link in the second one, and the edit privileges page link shifting from `edit privileges` to `peer reviewed`.

On desktop, I'm presented with almost the same banners... **Except that in the first case, there's just text, no links! And the first sentence is gone as well.** Those info and links​ seem pretty relevant, and I'm sure more people edit from computers than phones, so it would make great sense to have the links there as well.

**Can the wording and links please be updated in the desktop version?** It's a bit funny that, for once, the mobile version is better than the desktop one.

---

Note: searching for [`edit link privilege mobile`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Edit+privilege+link+mobile) didn't seem to bring up a dupe.

Comment: Screenshots are a pain to deal with on my phone, hence why there are none. I'd be glad if anyone could  edit some in :)

Comment: @Rob no and no - the screenshots are "after the fact" (once the edit has been suggested), as for duplication it's not tackling the same thing: it was a bug in a banner not showing, while the new question is more about making the two banners the same. (Which, surprisingly enough, they're not)

Comment: The app doesn't even have a banner at all...