# What do you do if someone forgot to format there code and there isn't enough to change to submit an edit?

Tags: discussion, support, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to overcome “Edits must be at least 6 characters”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters)

I tried to edit an answer but I can't because "[e]dits must be at least 6 characters".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave it for someone with more reputation to repair.