# Edits 6 characters limitation case

Tags: discussion, edits

When I found missing '=' in codes, I cannot edit coz of Edits have limitation, at least 6 character must change.

Comment: See also: [How to overcome "Edits must be at least 6 characters"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81520)

Comment: Also, consider writing an answer or comment to inform the OP of the mistake, rather than edit and fix it. The question should start as and remain a *problem* and the answer the *solution*, so together they form a Q&A. If you fix the code in the question then arguably the answer(s) are not valid and neither is the question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of just attempting to fix a missing character, try and find what else is wrong with the post, such as fixing spelling/grammar, formatting the question correctly, or anything else you deem worthy to edit.

The problem with just adding a character is the edit would be *too minor*. It's recommended you try to fix up as much of the post as you can within an edit, as I have talked about above.

If there is nothing else to fix up, then just leave the post. Feel free to message the OP saying that they are missing the `'='`, but really, it shouldn't be that catastrophic.