# Can a question be put on hold by a single person?

Tags: discussion

I am referring to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19805269/submit-form-in-html-by-java-uploading-file#19805269)
As far as I know a question will be put on hold if the same gets 5 votes to close and after the question is put on hold user names are displayed like **put on hold as unclear what you're asking byxx,uy,oo,pp,jj♦ 8 mins ago** But in this question only one name is displayed.So is it possible to keep a question on hold by a single user.If yes then please tell me what should be the minimum reputation required to do so?

Comment: Here is a [sample](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204398/216721) of the doings of a diamond moderator on MSO too.

Comment: Regarding question ban you asked about in comments below, [deleting your own questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193191/152859) won't do you any good in general.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Thanks for your response.Well can you please tell me are there any limits of deleting own questions or getting downvotes and if crosses then limit then I will be banned from posting question

Comment: Yes there are limits even here on Meta but the exact formula is secret. All I can do is advice you to try and search before asking, and don't delete questions just because they got some downvotes.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd yes sure I will do,but please tell me do i have to earn certain reputation to know the formula?

Comment: @javaBeginner you have to be hired by Stack Exchange as a developer, only then you might have access to the actual code and formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normal users, no matter their reputation, cannot unilaterally close a question. Diamond moderators (so named because of the diamond appearing after their name), however, can. New diamond moderators are periodically elected by the community. You can see [the current list of diamond moderators here](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators). For more information, see [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)

Comment: Thanks for the answer,+1 for the same.In Stackoverflow if we ask poor question so we get downvotes and after some time we are banned from posting questions.Is the same thing applicable in meta also.I got many down votes in previous question and the same I expect from this too as it is a duplicate.

Comment: @javaBeginner: From what I understand, there is a post ban on Meta as well, but the thresholds are such that it is more difficult to trigger.

Comment: @if I am banned from posting on meta then can i post questions on stackoverflow?

Comment: @javaBeginner - These doubts you're asking could make up for another question as such. I really think that you can ask a new question, as it might be useful for future users too, who might have the exact same doubt! :)

Comment: @javaBeginner - Best thing to do is search. All of these questions have already been asked and answered. Think of Meta Stack Overflow like one big user manual on how to use Stack Exchange sites. Just like on the main site, if you search and don't find an answer, then it's a good time to ask a question. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: @javaBeginner: No; in the best case they will just be migrated to Meta after some comments suggesting you should have posted it here originally (which, of course, you would have been unable to do). I'm not sure what you'd do if you're post-banned from Meta; I haven't ever been in that situation and I hope you won't ever be either.

Comment: @jmort253 Actually I didnt know if anybody has the diamond symbol then he is a modertor.

Comment: @icktoofay I mean to say can i post coding related question in stackoverflow if I am banned from meta.

Comment: @javaBeginner - Sure, but what I'm trying to say is that you're making us answer questions that you can search for. We don't mind helping :)  I just want to point out that answers are there for you to find via the search. I use it quite a bit when I have questions about how the site works. Search is your friend.

Comment: @javaBeginner: Yes, if you are post-banned from Meta then you should still be able to post programming questions on Stack Overflow; as far as I know, a post ban on one site does not affect the other. I'm pretty sure that you aren't in danger of being post-banned from Meta yet, though. As I said, the thresholds are pretty high, relatively speaking, although I would continue endeavoring to avoid excessive downvotes.

Comment: Thanks you have cleared all my doubts.well can i know thresholds?

Comment: @javaBeginner: As far as I know, the thresholds are not public.

Comment: Also [Community Managers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338/187824) can close the post with one vote too.

Comment: @hims056 true, but they also have diamond - on all sites. So you can say "any user with diamond next to his/her name can insta-close/delete any post". That said sometime [SE employees get super powers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/154882/152859) without a diamond - now *that* can be confusing. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Yeah, I mentioned Community Managers because icktoofay has linked the moderators' page. So if someone see a question closed by CM but can't find him/her in moderators' page, he may get confused. :)

Comment: @hims056 same goes to the team/devs - it never ends! :D