# Minimal number of character changes for editing should be relative to post length

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I was trying to edit [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/224218/228067) to improve its formating and fix a typo error. But it prevents me to submit the edit as edits should be at least 6 characters.

Original:

> Or tou can put in your /etc/apt/apt.conf something like this:
>
> ```
> Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://user:pass@host:port/";
> ```

My Edit:

> Or you can put in your `/etc/apt/apt.conf` something like this:
>
> ```
> Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://user:pass@host:port/";
> ```

I *cannot* improve this post further more. What should I do in such situations?

Comment: "You can put something like this in `/ab/cd.ef`" would be an improvement

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81520/158100

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, after looking at this post, I appreciate the fact that we have an edits' lower bound.

**Why?**

Answers like that (one-line or just giving a short code or command) aren't really considered as good in the Stack Exchange.  (Looks like his first post. So, welcome him and ask him to elaborate on his answer.)

So, I would ask the answerer to expand on his answer a bit, so that it explains where the OP went wrong, and how his answer helps him.

So, you can consider doing them same, or just comment underneath his answer with your edit suggestion, so that he can do it himself.

In its current state, you cannot edit the answer, and I don't think the edit lower-bound should be tweaked according to the answer length, due to the arguments provided above.