# Converting text format to code format, not enough change to be considered an edit

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits

If a code portion of an answer is not formatted correctly and I edit it, it is not considered a valid edit unless I change 6 characters.

But what if I only want to update the format of the answer and not change the answer itself.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to overcome "Edits must be at least 6 characters"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81522/289905).

Comment: Get to 2k ASAP. Until that, posts with such formatting problems have some other to improve, too. Just find the reason. :-) If it has really nothing (unlikely) then you are stuck, but it is rare. Note: if it is a question, then also re-tagging might help a lot to find it easier.

Comment: Another important thing: reviewers like to reject your edit suggestion saying "no improvement". This is a bad thing in the system, so try to avoid it by making all your improvements the possible largest.